# Double integral polar coordinate using substitution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I have to calculate:

$$\iint _{R} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}dA$$

and R is this region:

$$x^{2}+y^{2}=16; x^{2}+y^{2}=4; y = \sqrt{3}x; y=\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$$

so I used substitution:

$$x = r\cos \theta \: \: \: \wedge \: \: \: y = r\sin \theta$$

therefore I have:

$$\int_{\frac{\pi }{6}}^{\frac{\pi }{3}}\int_{2}^{4}\frac{rcos\theta }{r}rdrd\theta$$

$$=6\left [ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \right ]$$

is this right way to approach this double integral?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Your region doesn't make sense, you have four lines (curves)...at best they intersect at a single (or multiple) points.  This does not define a region (assuming to be a 2D shape)...I think you need inequalities.

Comment: In the region limited by the curves...?

Comment: I think my professor was not completely accurate but I understood the common region of all this curves